# Cluecumber - is it possible to change scenario-detail files naming?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

cluecumber version: 2.2.0

By default scenario-detail files are named as 'scenario_1', 'scenario_2' etc.

Is there any possibility to change 'scenario_1.html' name to scenarioName.html automatically ?
I need constant url to single scenario in my report. I think it is better to use scenario name instead of tags - it is my secondary solution but I am not satisfied

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is deliberately named like this since scenario names are not unique. This would create more problems than it would solve.